# How to integrate nginx with a caching mechanism

Tags: caching, nginx, memcached

We are using nginx in order to serve static map tiles. Tiles (png files) are stored on disk. We think that it is slow and cumbersome for nginx to retrieve files each and every time. Therefore, we plan to keep the most used tiles in cache.

Is it possible to integrate nginx with a caching mechanism such as Memcached?

Answer (score 0):

If it's static files I recommend to use expires for cache file on client machine.

Please see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html

Also you may setting gzip.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. What about the softwares like Memcached? Is it possible to use self-proven products?

Comment: Yes, you can. Memcached module: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_memcached_module.html location ~* \.(gif|jpg|png)$ {
  default_type            text/html;
  set $memcached_key      "$server_name:$request_uri";
  memcached_pass          127.0.0.1:11211;
  error_page              404 502 504 = @fallback;
}

Comment: Thanks but through my research I read that nginx can read the data from memcached but cannot post it. If that is the case, I cannot use it.